# Mac Pro 6,1 is overheating under Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: hardware, mac, overheating, fan, temperature

This MacPro computer is used as a server and never shutdown. Sometimes, after some hard cpu intensive usage, or the sun goes on the computer, the MacPro is crashing.

Thus I moved it far from the sun. But it seems the computer got a problem with the temperature detection. And it never make any noise (But the fan is slowly turning). And i am able to detect temperatures with alternative software such as `lm-sensors`.

Did some people had trouble with MacPro hardware and overheating on ubuntu?

**How can I diagnosis this kind of problem and correct it?**

My system description is as follow:

```
➜  ~ sudo dmidecode -s system-product-name
MacPro6,1

➜  ~ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

---

I tried to install `lm-sensors` and `fancontrol`. And `lm-sensors` works well 
But after following all the information to set up the `/etc/fancontrol` file I got the following file:

```
INTERVAL=10
DEVPATH=devices/platform/applesmc.768
DEVNAME=applesmc
FCTEMPS=hwmon0/device/pwm1=hwmon2/device/temp102_input
FCFANS=hwmon0/device/pwm1=hwmon2/device/fan1_input
MINTEMP=hwmon0/device/pwm1=20
MAXTEMP=hwmon0/device/pwm1=45
MINSTART=hwmon0/device/pwm1=150
MINSTOP=hwmon0/device/pwm1=0
```

But when I execute `sudo fancontrol` I go the following message error:

```
Settings for hwmon0/device/pwm1:
  Depends on hwmon2/device/temp102_input
  Controls hwmon2/device/fan1_input
  MINTEMP=20
  MAXTEMP=45
  MINSTART=150
  MINSTOP=0
  MINPWM=0
  MAXPWM=255

Device path of devices/platform/applesmc.768 has changed
Device name of applesmc has changed
Configuration appears to be outdated, please run pwmconfig again
```

---

I just added `macfanctld` package. 
Now my computer fan speed is always very high. (It modified the minimum fan speed to *2000 RPM*).

```
sensors  
applesmc-isa-0300
Adapter: ISA adapter
Main :       1998 RPM  (min = 2000 RPM, max = 2161 RPM)
TA0P:         +31.8°C  
TA0V:         +29.8°C 
...
```

I tried to update my file `/sys/devices/platform/applesmc.768/fan1_min` from *2000* to *0*. But it stop the fan for *5s* (the period of update i presume). And the the minimum speed is reset to *2000*.

This new setup doesn't really annoy me but it's not perfect (for electric consumption and noise).